# i am currently working on selenium and i want to select a dropdown but it has no id and its class matches with the class of other dropdowns too

Tags: html, python-3.x, dropdown

```html
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Schedule<span class="caret"></span></a>
this is the HTML code of dropdown "Schedule"
which i want to select

<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">User Management<span class="caret"></span></a>
this is the HTML code of dropdown"User Management"
which is being selected
```

I used find_element_by_class_name("class name")
but it selects another dropdown as it has the same class name,
so i checked with HTML codes and found that both dropdowns are almost same and do not have any id

i tried using mouse hover too but it also needs something to specify the address of that dropdown but the address af two dropdowns are same

schedule=driver.find_element_by_class_name("dropdown-toggle")
schedule.click()

it selects another dropdown which I don't want to select

Comment: Try looking into XPath.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the list of elements by class name first, then access specific element by index.

```py
elements = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("your_class_name");
el = elements[x];
```

Note: x=0 (1st element), x=1 (2nd element), etc.